# Cannot request from React. Always showing session-token error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, express-session

I'm having 2 servers { React:3000 and Node:5000 }
I'm using express-session in my backend,
but whenever I request from React( Axios ) with correct Session-Token,
It always shows Bad-Session-Token.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Session Conf:

```
    const mongoDBstoreSess = new MongoDBStore({
        uri: "mongodb://localhost:27017/SomeDb",
        collection: "mySessions"
    });
    app.use(
        session({
          name: "SomeCookie",
          secret: "SuperSecret",
          resave: true,
          saveUninitialized: false,
          store: mongoDBstoreSess,
          cookie: {
            maxAge: 7.2e+6,
            // sameSite: false,
            secure: false,
            httpOnly: false
          }
        })
    );
    app.use(csrf());
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // console.log(require('ip').address());
      if (err.code !== 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') return next(err);
      res.type("application/json").status(403).send({msg: "Session error.", res: {}});
      console.log("Bad Session!");
    });
```

React Axios Request Object:

```
{
      method: "post",
      url: "",
      baseURL: site.reqUrl,
      headers: {"CSRF-Token":"lkIpPT8A-ts2YcBc_YggWDYwe5f74k8jTWHM"},
      // xsrfHeaderName: "CSRF-Token",
      data: {},
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token must be got from login or another method to retrieve token.
When token has been retrieved from server, you have to store it in storage / cookie.
Then use the token in axios request object.